# Running Node.js on iOS as a server and let other device connected in

Tags: javascript, android, ios, node.js, html

I am building a card game app on iOS and android which with the following logic:

1. People download the app from App Store / Google Play
2. They can play the game offline with other players within the same wifi-network
3. One client will act as a server, while other players will act as clients
4. The game is an app with Node.js, SQLite embedded
5. Each player's move will be saved in the server
6. When there's internet access, the iOS act as server will send the data to cloud

**My approach is**

1. The game will be a HTML5 with Node.js, the player act as a game holder(server) will open a port (like port 80)
2. Other players will use HTTP get/set to send and receive the JSON package to and from game holder

**My questions is**

1. Will it be possible for me to run Node.js on iOS, as a server and open ports to let other players connect in? So that I can use JSON for all the communications between players.
2. If not, what will be the best way for different device (iOS, android, Windows Phone) communicate?

Any suggestions and help will be appreciated. Thanks.
Michael

Comment: I don't think you can run node.js on iOS without Jail-broken it. use parse.com as the backend would be a good option. parse is running some thing like nodejs

Comment: If iOS only. there is native API to connect devices within local network. You can find the example in Apple Developer Center

Comment: Another option is websocket. you can use websocket communicate between clients. it would be a HTML5 app which embedded into a webview

Comment: @EricSo Thank you for the information, can the websocket open the port on iOS and Android, so that I can open port 80 within the HTML5 app and let other device send / receive data using HTTP calls?

Answer (score 1):

My reputation is not enough to comment but I will suggest what to use anyway. If you make a server in Node.js, then the rest of this answer will tell you what to do. Use CFNetwork and CoreFoundation. Assuming you are sending data in string format, this code should help (the code sends a string to a server).

```
    import CoreFoundation
    import CFNetwork

    var outputStream: NSOutputStream!

    var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStreamRef>?

    var addr: CFString = "127.0.0.1"

    var port: UInt32 = 80 
    //the second nil in CFStreamCreatePairWithHost is a read stream. which means it reads data. we don't need it bc we are only sending data

    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(nil, addr, port, nil, &writeStream)
        outputStream = writeStream!.takeRetainedValue()

        outputStream.delegate = self

        outputStream.open()

        outputStream.write("fireGun", maxLength: 8 //(the char count of fireGun")
        //close outputStream
        outputStream.close()
```

Comment: but he wants the app can be used offline as well  2. They can play the game offline with other players within the same wifi-network

Comment: have not looked you code. I thought you were talking about connecting to a nodejs server

Comment: @RichterB. The main target of my app will be user can use their iOS / Anrdoid device as a server, while other players can connect with that a as a client and play the game within the same wifi network, so my main concern is there any way to deploy the Node.js within my app and build a HTTP server inside my app. Thanks for your info.